# Attempted to repair install XP froze @ 98% and now nothing will display after a restart

Tags: windows, windows-xp, display

Was trying to recover a prior Windows install so that I could access remaining files and reformat, but now even a boot CD/USB won't show up. Everything (CD disk drive & hard drive) sounds like they are spinning up, but the display is not initializing and not showing me a MOBO splash, BIOS, or any POST info.

As a matter of fact Screen is plugged in and set to on with the signal cables in place of course, but the monitor still is not accepting the display signal from the PC. Was working with absolutely no hiccups prior the the XP repair process from boot.

(Heres the sequence of what's happened)
boot from legit XP install CD > install > repair install > prompts & wait for progress bar to finish. 3 hours later progress is stuck at 98% > force reboot > fan HDD and Disk spins but display no longer works.

Any clues as to what's going on here and steps I can try to recover the native display driver?

Comment: This is P4 hardware with an ASUS mobo I have an old Nvidea Dual DVI video card which I used primarily, but the Integrated MOBO has VGA (which I never used) neither work.

Answer (score 0):

If the display isn't even showing up at POST then this isn't a driver issue, in fact it's not a Windows issue of any kind but rather a hardware one. Could just be a monitor or display card issue though I'm guessing from the way it crashed during an install it could also be more serious.

I'd recover the hard drive by removing it from the case and plugging it into another machine and imaging from there, and once that was done I'd start investigating the hardware issue... or given the type of hardware I'd scrap it as it must be over 5 years old and that's well past the point where its reasonable to spend any more of the businesses' time and money on fixing it.